# Unable to zoom in using ggOceanMaps?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to use the following to create a map of an area:   lat (35,32)  lon (-119,-116) in ggOceanMaps. I am unable to get my map to focus in on the area specified. This results in a flat plot that is not legible. I used the following website for reference. Perhaps there are similar packages operating using these rules? Four values are required for latitude and longitude.
https://mikkovihtakari.github.io/ggOceanMaps/

```
# Code given: dt <- data.frame(lon = c(-30, -30, 30, 30), lat = c(50, 80, 80, 50)) 
basemap(data = dt)
# Modified: 
dt <- data.frame(lon,lat)
# where
lon = (-119,-116)
lat = (35,32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```r
library(ggOceanMaps)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggspatial
#> Setting data download folder to a temporary folder
#> /var/folders/fm/xtn13rlj7d3gp8twy7hh9prxtlq_m4/T//RtmptFmQ0Z. This
#> means that any downloaded map data need to be downloaded again when you
#> restart R. To avoid this problem, change the default path to a
#> permanent folder on your computer. Add following lines to your
#> .Rprofile file: {.ggOceanMapsenv <- new.env(); .ggOceanMapsenv$datapath
#> <- 'YourCustomPath'}. You can use usethis::edit_r_profile() to edit the
#> file.'~/Documents/ggOceanMapsLargeData'would make it in a writable
#> folder on most operating systems.
packageVersion("ggOceanMaps")
#> [1] '1.1.10'
basemap(limits =c(-119, -116, 32, 35))
#> Using lon and lat as longitude and latitude columns, respectively.
#> projection transformed from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:4326
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>